# Concatenating numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to concatenate 0s and 1s in a matrix to form a binary number (as a string).
For example, `[1 0 1;0 0 1]` should output `['101';'001']`

When trying this input however, I get `['1','1']` as a result. Why?

```
function result = generateBinary(ref_matrix)
    [row col] = size(ref_matrix);
    result = cell(1,row);

    str = '';

    for i=1:row
        for j = 1:col
            n = num2str(ref_matrix(i,j))
            str = strcat(str, num2str(ref_matrix(i,j)));      
            str
        result{1,i} = str;    
        str = '';
        end
    end    
end
```

Comment: You may replace this function with `char(ref_matrix+'0')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `end` is at the wrong place.

```
function result = generateBinary(ref_matrix)
[row col] = size(ref_matrix);
result = cell(1,row);

str = '';

for i=1:row
    for j = 1:col
        n = num2str(ref_matrix(i,j))
        str = strcat(str, num2str(ref_matrix(i,j)));      
        str
    end
    result{1,i} = str;    
    str = '';
end
```

As the indent suggests, `result{1,i} = str;str = '';` may not be part of the inner loop.